# Proof assistants with dynamic scope/local instances/etc.?

Tags: design, mathematics

Say I'm formalizing something in group theory, and I'm working with some action $\cdot$ of $(G, +)$ on a set. In my math textbook, the identity of $\cdot$ is explicitly mentioned once (if that), and then left implicit. In my formalization, do I have to constantly keep specifying $(G, \cdot)$, or can I temporarily set $\cdot$ as the default?

In my limited experience, mathematical writing uses "dynamic scope" like this a lot. Does this actually correspond to a computer scientist's definition of dynamic scope, and if so, do any proof assistants support this?

Comment: The way to do something like this depends a lot on your proof assistant.  For instance, Coq has sections and modules; Agda has a different sort of module.

Comment: IIRC, ACL2 has the same dynamic scoping of Common Lisp.

Comment: I think you just need to find your proof assistant where you will be satisfied with the look of theorems. There is no so called right way to implement abstract algebra library. It is more like market where you choose.

Comment: This is, imo, a way to specify local instances, not the "dynamic scoping" in traditional PL sense

Comment: It is not clear from your question which of several proof assistant techniques suits your needs. You could be asking whether you can mention the neutral element without mentioning the group. You could be asking whether you can construct a group without specifying the unit. Or maybe you just want to say "whenever you see variable `x` assume its type is `t`" (which is how people are interpreting your question). It would be helpful if you gave a specific example of what you'd like. Also, what you are looking for is *not* called dynamic scope.

Comment: Another option: you want to say "in this part, let us have a group $(G, \cdot)$ and whenever I mention anything related to a group, I mean $G$". Is that what you'd like?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I was more thinking along the lines of "we have a group $(G, \cdot)$ and whenever I mention a group operation on $G$, I mean $\cdot$."

Comment: I think y'all are correct that local instances are what I'm thinking about in this specific example, rather than dynamic scope *per se* (maybe I can think of an example specific to the latter).

Answer (score 4):

Agda has [generalization of declared variables](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/language/generalization-of-declared-variables.html). In short, you can leave a variable block of variables that are appearing often.

Example:

```
variable
  g : Grammar

first-item : symbol g -> Item g
```

It implicitly adds the `{g:Grammar} ->` in front of the `first-item`.

There's another system that lets you do this on variables, called [modules](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/language/module-system.html). And here's an example of using that:

```
module FinMap (k : Set)
              (size : ℕ) where
   maxSize : ℕ
   maxSize = size
```

You can later open this kind of a module and fill in the pieces. Possibly within another module, if your fill-up depends on implicits.

```
module ItemSet {g : Grammar} {n : ℕ} where
  open FinMap.FinMap (EIM g n) (eim-size g n) public
    using (maxSize)
```

These are syntactic-sugar features relying on implicits. It behaves a lot like a dynamic scope in practice.

Comment: This looks a lot like how variables and modules work in Coq (I think)... but it hadn't occurred to me to emulate "local instances" in this way. I come from Haskell, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around ML-like modules :-) Purely out of curiosity, does Agda use typeclasses as well as modules—and if so, is there a solution like this for them as well?

Comment: @JoshuaGrossoReinstateCMs Agda has typeclasses as well, but I don't know how do they work. manual page: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.1/language/instance-arguments.html

Answer (score 3):

In Isabelle/Isar `locale` can be used to specify implicit assumptions and notation conventions that are limited in scope. The assumptions are then added to each theorem proven in the locale. With the `sublocale` keyword one can define how notation maps from one context (locale) to another so that theorems can be reused in a different context.